# Weirdness calling str() to convert integer to string in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shadowing

Why is this giving me an error?

```
>>> variable = str(21)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#101>", line 1, in <module>
    variable = str(21)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: did you name a variable "str"?

Comment: Did you define another string variable and assign it to a variable `str` ? because doing so you end up shadowing the builtin function `str()` e.g: `str = 'test'; print(str(124))`.

Comment: The downvotes are misplaced. Most of us have shadowed builtins, when learning. Look how many code examples out there with `list = [...]`. I updated the title of this question.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

That code alone won't give you an error. For example, I just tried this:

```
~ $ python3.2
>>> variable = str(21)
>>> variable
'21'
```

Somewhere in your code you're defining that `str =` something else, masking the builtin definition of `str`. Remove that and your code will work fine.

Answer (score 14):

Because you've probably overwritten the `str` function by calling your own variable `str`.

Comment: I think you might be right. I closed out of my IDLE session (which had a lot of earlier code samples I found online loaded), and now I can use the built-in str function properly. One of those earlier code samples must have done something quirky to the BIF str(). Thanks!